# Semantic Mediawiki error: processing error text "@category " cannot be used as a property name in this wiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

Following [this guide](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Adding_subobjects) I've created a [page](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Tutti_gli_articoli_di_Marco_Crepaldi) with the following source code

```
{{#subobject:mysubobject
|url = https://www.instagram.com/p/CXeE2j-NT6s/
|title = Bullismo: proposta una legge in Francia per punirlo penalmente. Si rischia anche il carcere
|@category = bullismo|violenza|leggi|punizioni|+sep=;
}}
```

But I get the following error message:

```
processing error text   "@category " cannot be used as a property name in this wiki.
```

Any hint on what's going on? I couldn't find any answer on google.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the space after `@category`. Also, note that a semicolon is used to separate several categories in your case:

```
{{#subobject:mysubobject
|url = https://www.instagram.com/p/CXeE2j-NT6s/
|title = Bullismo: proposta una legge in Francia per punirlo penalmente. Si rischia anche il carcere
|@category=bullismo;violenza;leggi;punizioni|+sep=;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a subobject you are creating proporties, you cannot give them a separate category. And here you are saying give me a property @category within my subobject.

Some classes/properties are protected. The name category is one of them